Open source work vs paying work and unsolicited contacts/help requests/job offers
Perhaps this is not appropriate for workplace.stackexchange but bear with me. I'm an indie software developer that makes a living splitting my time between maintaining and managing sales of an app I created, and doing some unrelated freelance development/consulting. In the past I've worked "regular jobs" for larger companies so I have a general idea of how corporate software dev gets done, but it's been a while since I worked a 9-5 or answered to a middle manager, so no doubt I am out of touch in some ways. During the course of my work (on both my own product and for consulting clients) over the years I've contributed to plenty of open source projects, mostly out of enlightened self interest (e.g. to fix a bug or add a feature to a library my work depended on). I've benefited greatly from open source and enjoy giving back, including helping people out on GitHub & SO etc., so consequently there's a lot of publicly googlable threads and message board posts I've participated in.
With increasing frequency, I get unsolicited contacts from folks who track me down from this public body of work. I don't know if this is just due to Google more heavily weighting results from dev sites of late. Sometimes it's straight up job offers which I can politely decline easily enough ("Your bugfix saved my company, do you want a job at [insert co. I definitely don't want a job at]?") although it's a little annoying when it's more aggro recruiter-y. Once in a while it directly leads to actual paying consulting work and that's great. But more troubling, and frequent, is when people hunt me down and personally email me for help with what is clearly commercial work, with seeming intention of getting as much of what is essentially free expert help out of me as possible. I don't want to ignore cold calls like this - or forget the general open source ethos of mutual benefit - and like I said occasionally they have led to quality paying work - but often things get awkward quickly when I have to say stuff like "no I won't 'hop on a call with your team' to help you without a payment arrangement in place" (yes this has actually happened).
So my questions, especially addressing other devs who may be reading this, sorry for taking so long to get to them: Is this common for other OSS devs out there? How do you handle it? And for anyone who might have been at the other end of a contact like this, what kind of thinking at companies leads to employees with their own paying tech jobs thinking it's totally ok to privately contact someone at random (outside of the normal public forums) and ask for free help with their job? I don't want to be the ahole, and I realize how fortunate I am to have reached the point where I can be independent in this field, but sometimes I feel that I have to be the ahole. And clearly sometimes these cold-callers are taken aback, and even pissed off, by my not immediately agreeing to help them for free. I get the sense many of them are actually quite desperate which is why they bothered to hunt down my contact info (not that hard to find but it does take a few clicks!) and not simply create an issue on GitHub or post to SO - while at the same time they're smart enough to know that their problem is too complex or esoteric to try asking for help publicly. Most recently someone emailed me unsolicited for help, and when I offered to do the work as a paid consultant, they said maybe but I would need to first do an unpaid meeting with them to see if "your skills align with our needs" - which sure sounded like a job interview for a job I never applied for at best, or a free consulting session at worst, coming from someone who surely already knew of my skills from my GitHub history which is the reason they sought me out  in the first place. Are these folks being unreasonable or am I? When do you draw the line and demand compensation for expert advice in the open source world? Is it even ok to do this while still respecting the spirit of open source? I try to draw a distinction between a hobbyist or nonprofit that I'll give my time to help, but sometimes it's hard to tell, and often it's clearly commercial in nature.
Full disclosure, I'm writing this from a burner account to remain anonymous (why this site doesn't allow anonymous posts when sensitive info is being shared, I don't understand...).

That really isn't a workplace question, but the answer is yes, if you make yourself visible people will randomly contact you for advice. Aggressive spam filtering, and using separate user IDs for personal versus open source versus commercial work, are probably your best tools.

@TheDemonLord that's an interesting comparison but a quite strange way to look at it... It suggests that contributions to open source projects are like showing off somehow? Is that how some people treat it? Rather than a professional act originating in most cases from a paid project? I look at open source projects as more akin to a doctor publishing research in a public journal - something that could be useful to others and help advance the field for the common good. Hard for me to see that as "provocative".

@keshlam I ask as a workplace question in part because of my own distance from and ignorance of whatever it means to have a corporate software dev job in 2024. Since it's people in those positions that are the types I'm getting contacted by. So my question is a kind of corporate etiquette one.

@LeCram - even the Doctor publishing research has an element of prestige and reputation as part of it. I'm not saying it is wrong, I'm saying that when you do something publicly, a part of you is doing so for attention (both good and bad) and complaining about the unwanted attention is not very sympathetic. You could make your contributions completely anonymous, divorced from your professional persona - but that would forgo the requests for paid consultancy work.

@TheDemonLord FWIW I'm talking about large open source projects I have contributed to but for which I have no control over their public status because I am not in charge of them. I did not choose to make my contributions public, but rather them becoming public was a consequence of my needing to for example fix a bug in a public library that I needed for a job. I didn't object to them becoming public obviously but neither did I know that it would lead to strangers blatantly hunting me down, sometimes years later.

Are the questionable requests usually in the name of their company or private inquiries? In other words, do you get asked to help out a team officially or rather to secretly do someone else’s work?

@MisterMiyagi I'm not sure. It certainly feels like I'm being asked to help someone else do their job, but I don't think it is being done in secret. That said, these people are choosing to contact me privately rather than post to a public forum.

This one seems trivial. Treat them as any other prospective client. "I'd be happy to help you with that, let me send you over my rate sheet and a template Statement of Work or you can use your own. If you want me to do the scoping, I can do that too".
Look, Linux is open source but that does in no way imply that anyone working with or on Linux should do so for free. That would be preposterous. You have no moral or ethical obligation at all to work for free. Quite on the contrary: you already DID work for free, so the people benefitting from this owe you, not the other way around.

My standard response, when I didn't want to engage, was: "I'm sorry, but I can't afford to give free support to the entire internet on an individual basis. If you want direct support, here's my hourly rate. If you want free support, post it to the bug list, wish list, or help list for that tool, and I or someone else will respond when time permits; that way the answer helps many people, not just one, and the burden on answerers is more fairly balanced." Note that the same answer is sometimes needed for people asking for support within your own organization.


When do you draw the line and demand compensation for expert advice in the open source world?

Whenever you want prior to doing the actual work.
Whether they seem upset or not makes no difference, or shouldn't.

I generally agree with this sentiment. But I also don't want to piss off the wrong guy that comes back to hurt me later in my career. So I guess part of my question is a kind of corporate etiquette question.

Corporate etiquette: You are always free to turn down an engagement. You are never required to respond to a cold call.

Pissing off people who want free work and get upset if they don't get it isn't a liability. I've told govt ministers to pay or pee off

@LeCram Lawyers don't answer questions without a payment process in place. Corporate etiquette is not a problem. Hold your ground as a professional.
